# Flowbit - Tailwind flex wrap issue

Tags: tailwind-css, flowbite

I'm using Flowbite components. I'm having issues with flex-wrap. as you can see in the screenshots when I check its responsiveness on iPhone 12 model level, it looks ok. But when I have a full screen in the browser, rendered cards do not align horizontally and instead go below. I also attached the chrome dev tool to show where I have applied the flex-wrap. Can you help me to find the issues, please?

stuck for two days already on this one

[image: fullwidth][image: mobile view]
[image: dev tool]

Comment: Please produce the reproducible code

Comment: Here is the code sandbox environment: shorturl.at/biuvL  Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: I see it is working perfectly fine even in the desktop mode. Could you please say what issues are you exactly facing?

Comment: It does not work on my desktop for some reason. As you can see in the first image, my rendered cards are shifting below. I cleared the chrome cache but still getting the same result for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Try this code: [Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/VtmnVRYFjz)

---

Everything is just working fine. According to the [url in the comment](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/BRashad/halalbaqqal/draft/prod-wood?create=true&file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2Ffilters%2FCities.jsx&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A1%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A14%2C%22startColumn%22%3A1%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A14%7D%5D)

The cards are aligned to the  right of the left navigation bar

Ouputs in different screens.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is strange since on my laptop the cards are shifting to the bottom (you can see the desktop image in my initial post). i cleared browser (chrome) cache, but it did not help.

Comment: It can't happen that way, try to open the said link in my post and open the chromes responsivness tab and try tweaking the screen size. It should work just fine!

Comment: Yes, it works fine as you say. But on my laptop on local host it does not.

Comment: but also the problem is that on mobile view the cards need to shift under the checkboxes. But they do not shift. What do you the problem is ?

Comment: I suggest you use `flex` instead of `flex-wrap` and make it responsive accross different devices, You are nesting `flex-wrap` inside `flex-wrap` this is causing the problem

Comment: i use flex-wrap on children (each card) and on two components "checkboxes and component where all cards" are rendered. if I take away flex-wrap the cards stop being responsive. Unless you know exactly how to do it.

Comment: I can show you how to make it responsive using `flex` if you need the same ! I would be happy to help, You  just have to let me know, for what screens meaning for small / large or small/medium/large or any , and how would you want the elements to be aligned in the respective screen. If you clear mention the layout you are looking for in every screen, I could help you out making it responsive

Comment: - On small screens, I need check boxes to come first, then cards
- On medium and big screens, checkboxes remain on the left side, but user cards decrease in the number of columns. Big will have 3 columns, medium 2.

I hope it makes sense.
Thank you so much in advance

Comment: This works ! I'll get back to you with the requird code after some while , got some work to catch up to!

Comment: It's presently only read, can i have write permission ? Or let me do it in playground, you'll get idea, then you can implement in your code.

Comment: See the link in my edited post and tell me if you need any further changes, I have designed it based on your demand. [Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/VtmnVRYFjz)

Comment: Sorry, it was late I went to bed. Thank you very much. If I want on the small screen size the number of columns to decrease/instead of three let's say to see all cards in one column so they are not so small. Shall use flex-wrap ?

Comment: No avoid flex-wrap all together. Use grid-cols-1 , try this https://play.tailwindcss.com/5CnmnFI5jY

Comment: One last question. Since i use react it means i will have to render two time columns like you show it in your example right ?

Comment: I am not pretty sure about it , actually I have tried my best to not render twice, as it was unavoidable because the first time it is responsive to multiple screens, so it couldn't have been used again, so i had to render it twice, yes for this example you would have to do it twice. If the post helped you reach your goal / given idea about reaching your goal, please consider upvoting and accepted the post . Thank you . Hope I helped you !

Comment: Thank you. You did, indeed! all the best